# Angular 2 app getting 404 core.js and browser.js when load by system.src.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, angular

I'm just getting started with Angular2, and I've followed the Angular2 quickstart and the tutorial.

Some context... When the user clicks a link in the top navbar of my webapp it makes a server side request.  The page returned to the browser is an Angular2 app (index.html).  The user can click localhost the home app or click localhost/customer the customer app.  I don't understand how Angular2, and more likely SystemJS, is treating the difference in URL when loading/importing modules.

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu1GQ.png)

When I load the home page the angular code works as expected where the view is rendered.  The home index.html has System.config 'packages' = '/home' and the System.import references 'home/boot'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                // the browser url is http://localhost
                "/home": {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        // the browser url is http://localhost
        System.import('home/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <div>
        <p th:text="#{home.welcome(${name})}">Welcome Message</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- ANGULAR HOME APP -->
        <home>Loading...</home>
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the customer page the browser gets a 404 loading browser.js and core.js.  It is system.src.js that cannot find localhost/customer/angular2/platform/browser.js or localhost/customer/angular2/core.js.  These imports are defined in my boot.ts and customer.component.ts.

boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
```

and customer.component.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
```

This is where I am stuck and not sure what system.src.js is trying to do or why it isn't loading the modules.

[404 Error Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqlGV.png)

My customer index.html has System.config packages set as '/' which I'm not clear on but seemed necessary as the browser url is localhost/customer.  **How should the System.config 'packages' option for this scenario be set?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
    <title>Customer</title>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                // the browser url is http://localhost/customer
                '/': {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        // the browser url is http://localhost/customer
        System.import('boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <div th:object="${customer}">
        <p>First Name: <span th:text="*{firstName}">FirstName</span></p>
        <p>Last Name: <span th:text="*{lastName}">LastName</span></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOMER APP -->
        <customer>Loading...</customer>         
    </div>      
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change the System.config packages to 'customer' the browser gets a 404 loading my customer boot.js (the compiled customer boot.ts).  This lead me down the road to a few other changes

Change customer index.html System.import('boot').then(...) to have .js on 'boot' so the browser can find it

```
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                // the browser url is http://localhost/customer
                "customer": {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        // the browser url is http://localhost/customer
        System.import('boot.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Change customer/boot.js to have .js on the name of my registered component './customer.component'.

```
System.register(['angular2/platform/browser', './customer.component.js'], function(exports_1) {
    ...
}
```

These changes result in the customer app working albeit with a typescript compiler error "cannot find module ./customer.component.js".

It doesn't seem right to hand edit the compiled boot.js file.  Is there a way to compile the .ts files so the generated .js files explicitly reference .js files?  This seems like I am barking up the wrong tree.

I feel there is something I am missing with the customer index.html and how one can configure the System.config options.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am missing some information here, but I had the same kind of problems. I had to fiddle with the System.config and tsconfig.json file. The compilerOptions: outDir sourceRoot in the tsconfig.json file enabled me to choose mine own typescript source and output directory. I had also exclude some files from the compile process.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"removeComments": false,
"noImplicitAny": false,

"noEmitOnError": true,
"outDir": "./wwwroot/app",
"sourceRoot": "scripts",
"inlineSources": true
},

"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"wwwroot",
"typings/main",
"typings/main.d.ts"
]
}
```

In mine System.config I had to make mine own mappings for several typescript modules.

```
System.config({
defaultJSExtensions: true,
packages: {
    'app': {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
},

map: {
    'rxjs': 'vendor/js/rxjs',
    'angular2': 'vendor/js/angular2'
}
});
```

Mine suggestions are:

1. Also look at your tsconfig.json file to solve compile problems.
2. With the help of the map option in the System.config you maybe can solve your runtime problems.